# SSH into Ubuntu From Mac using Public Key

Tags: macos, terminal, ssh-keys

I am on Mac 10.11.5.

I have the public key server.ppk file for an Ubuntu server locked down to be accessed only by people on my local network.  I have downloaded the ppk file and changed the chmod to 0600.  In terminal I enter ssh -i server.ppk username@ipaddress

I get an alert message: 
'Enter your password for the SSH key "server.ppk".'

There isn't one.  I have tried leaving it blank with and without the 'Remember password in my keychain' box checked.  It gives me an error message "Saving password to keychain failed" 3 times before it fails out saying 'Permission denied (publickey)'.

I know the public key is correct as my boss is using it successfully on his windows machine.  I have tried both ssh and sftp on both terminal and transmit.  I have also tried adding -vvv which shows that it is connecting although I will admit to not being smart enough to understand most of what it gave back to me but essentially it asks me for the password 3 times and fails out like above.

I have bootcamp installed so I tried switching over to Windows 10, installed OpenSSL and tried again both ssh and sftp with the same results.

Is there something special I need to do on the Mac to accept a public key without a passphrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This publick key is probably a puttyGen generated key.

To transform this public key to a OpenSSH key you need to download putty-key-generator in  a windows machine (you can achieve this through [this](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/puttygen.exe) link), load your ppk key, and then through the menu `Conversion -> Export OpenSSH key`, transform it into a Linux compatible key.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry my response is so delayed. I just got back to this project today.  I followed your instructions and after changing the chmod to 600 it worked!  Thank you.